# Parse json data with JS being received from php

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

My form:

```
          <form class="form-inline signup" action="php/signupForm.php" role="form" id="signupForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme ladda-button" data-style="expand-left">
<span class="ladda-label" id="notice">Get notified!</span>
</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

the end of my php script

```
$response = array(
    "status" => $status,
    "message" => $message
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

My page is receiving data like:

```
{"status":0,"message":"This email is already on list!"}
```

using JS I need to parse that data and then update text within an element.

```
 <span id="notice">Get notified!</span>
```

here's my script which doesn't work, after senging form data to my php script I get a white screen that shows the json strong

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
      dataType: 'json',
        $('#notice').text(data.message);
      });
    });
```

Comment: If you are getting a screen of the response then you are doing a regular form submit instead of preventing the form from being submitted (ie using preventDefault in onsubmit event) and then doing the ajax call. With the code listed you are executing your ajax call as soon as your main page loads, not when you submit a form

Comment: I think your right and I think I've done this before. So to fix do I execute ajax onclick submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the response in a callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          url: $(this).attr('action'), // Or the path of the PHP file
          dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function(response) {
          $('#notice').text(response.message);
        });
    });
});
```

See the related docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: What url would go there, it's coming back to the page from the server?

Comment: The url of the PHP script you're calling

Comment: In the network tab of your browser debugger, so you see your call being fired ? My guess is that you're not referring to the right php file in the `url` parameter

Comment: the request url is the same thing. debugger shows a status200. requested method is 'get' could that be my problem?  do i need a method get?

Comment: see my updated anwser, that details how to handle the call itself.

Comment: For the `GET` vs `POST`, that will affect how you will use the data in your php script, i suggest that you use a `POST` for this, and you will be able to manipulate the posted data in your PHP script in the `$_POST` array

Comment: That's preventing my php script from running now. Let me include more code. Thank you btw for your help

Comment: So it's partly working I think. My db is updating however the message within the element isn't changin

Comment: WORKING! THANK YOU PASCAL

Answer (score 1):

That ajax call is not well formed, missing success callback and url e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/the/url/where/your/data/comes/from/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#notice').text(data.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code as is, is just executing at page load and not on submission of a form. You need to attach an onsubmit event, prevent the default action of doing the form submit and do your ajax call in there. Also your ajax call itself was malformed

```
$("#yourFormID").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       url:"/urlToServerScript",
       data:{} //any form data the script needs you should be put here,
       dataType:"json" //type of response the server will output
    }).then(function(data){
       $('#notice').text(data.message);
    });
});
```

Comment: but the data is already coming back to the page from the php script. I just need something to handle that returning data. I'm probably misunderstanding you here

Comment: @Rhillz, _"after senging form data to my php script I get a white screen that shows the json strong"_, This indicates that the data isn't "coming back" through an AJAX request though, you are doing a regular html form submit that causes the browser to navigate away from the current page to the server response. If you are wanting to stay on the current page and still submit data to a server script this is how you would do it

Comment: but it is my sql is updating

Comment: i see what your saying

Comment: Can I leave the data:{},  method empty and all of my data from form will get sent?

Comment: you can do `data:$(this).serialize()` I think

Comment: @Rhillz, that is not a method its an object literal being assigned to the `data` property, either do as Pascal mentions or propulate the object with the required data from your form. If you do not know how to do this then you need to go back and learn the basics of javascript before trying to use libraries like jQuery and doing ajax type pages.